# I see files in Filezilla, but the internet denies their existance

Tags: web-hosting, 404, ftp

I am doing some updates to a 10-year old site, and I am baffled.  Everything worked great locally, so I uploaded a bunch of stuff to the server using Filezilla.  Within Filezilla I can see all of the files, but for some reason I get a 404 when trying to view them.

It seems as though (at least for the folder I'm currently checking) this is happening for items which are "farther down the list" alphabetically.  I tried to re-upload a file individually but it didn't change anything.

Is this an indication that I hit some sort of limit with the hosting company?  And if so why can I still view the files from Filezilla?

Comment: One thing work checking is if you've got the case exactly right. Non-Windows servers are very often case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, can you upload a unique file to the root dir and then check on the internet that it is there. Just wondering if you have for some reason connected to the wrong area/account. Have done this myself before.

Also, can you clear the whole directory and then upload one of the "non-working" files and test?

Or create a sub directory and upload to that, testing one file at a time.

Give us a list of the file names & directories, and a url we can test?

Also as Paulmorriss says, check the file name case as non windows servers are a bit fussy about this. You have F5'd/refreshed Filezilla to double check the directory does contain these files

Comment: I will try the unique file / subdirectory ideas out.  The directory is http://ercolehome.com/images/products/mirrors/ one specific file: http://ercolehome.com/images/products/mirrors/SM36_3M.jpg  I thought of case sensitivity, and checked and double checked, refreshed and double refreshed.  Not the problem.

Comment: just added: http://ercolehome.com/images/products/mirrors/wtf.txt and that works...

Comment: Change the .jpg to .JPG in the URL and it works

Comment: Hahahah, i sorted it out... Im sorry to  bother you guys.  It WAS a case issue (with the file extension).  jpg != JPG.  I could swear I checked that several times

Comment: Good news. Helps to explain it to someone else and through this process you spot where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer with the SM36_3M.jpg file, you need to make sure the extension is uppercase:
http://ercolehome.com/images/products/mirrors/SM36_3M.JPG

The way I found this out was by going to here

http://ercolehome.com/images/products/mirrors/

You might want to turn off directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

That's because all the files can be upload but viewing the file in the internet is not allowed. There are certain restriction that prohibits anyone to see the file.